# Boxes appear under textarea in internet explorer

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer

Please could someone tell me why the red boxes appear below the textarea in chrome and others (as they should), but in internet explorer, they appear adjacent to the textarea.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <style>
    .wrapper { width: 760px; }
    textarea { float: left; width: 100%; height: 200px;}
    textarea { box-sizing: border-box; }
    li { float: left; margin: 10px; width: 175px; height: 175px; background-color: red; }
    fieldset{ margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; }
  </style>

</head>
<body>

  <div id="content" class="wrapper">
    <form>
      <textarea></textarea>
      <fieldset>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <img alt="/" src="/" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <img alt="/" src="/" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <img alt="/" src="/" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <img alt="/" src="/" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <img alt="/" src="/" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <img alt="/" src="/" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <img alt="/" src="/" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <img alt="/" src="/" />
          </li>
        </ul>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/deathwishdave/s9wct/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following.

Assuming I have interpreted your request correctly, it seemed to work for me.

```
     .wrapper { width: 760px; }
    textarea { float: left; width: 100%; height: 200px; display: block; }
    textarea { box-sizing: border-box; }
    li { float: left; margin: 10px; width: 175px; height: 175px; background-color: red; }
    fieldset{ margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; display: inline; }
```